# Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Auth/ForgotPasswordController]

Tags: php, laravel

I seem to get this issue every time I make a new invokable controller with a route. Can anyone help me fix it? I've tried deleting and remaking the class, remaking the route, it seems to hate it?

God knows how I got my ones before this working.

Route:

```
Route::post('user/forgot', 'Auth/ForgotPasswordController');
```

Controller;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->sendResetLinkEmail(request());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it!

```
Route::post('user/forgot', 'Auth/ForgotPasswordController');
```

Notice the `/` in the second paramater `Auth/ForgotPasswordController`

You need to change it to `\`, because this is the character for indicating a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In your post route, you have not specified method name, list your route using

```
php artisan route:list
```

you must see route like this,

```
| POST | password/email| password.email| App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail     | web,guest
```

you can do this way if you want to change default Auth route structure,

```
Route::post('user/forgot', 'Auth/ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
```

Comment: I'm not specifying a method name because I'm using an invokable controller, I don't need one.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are **case-sensitive**.
Make sure namespaces perfectly match the case of your directory hierarchy and class names.